# json.loads() (JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0))

Tags: python, json

I am trying to use json.load() but it is not working.

```
url = "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/" + ";".join(indicators) + 
source + date_range + per_page
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
result = response.content
result = json.loads(result)
result
```

But I get this error any ideas?
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2y3W.png)

Comment: Maybe no data was available to decode?

Comment: Please post text as text, not an image of text.  What is the JSON you are trying to decode?

Comment: when I print result = response.content there is data

Comment: Without seeing the value of `result`, it's not possible to see the reason for the `JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: Always check the response code before decoding. (Even if the examples in the docs don't do it.)

Comment: the response code is <Response [200]>

Comment: did you remember to add `&format=json` to your url? if you didnt you will get an XML which will not load as json

Comment: @Nullman no I did not do that how would one proceed with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

globalbank api defaults to XML, you need to tell it which format you need. try it like this:

```
url = "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/" + ";".join(indicators) + source + date_range + per_page + '&format=json'
```